# Hadoop Namenode send FSNamesystem metrics to graphite with corrupted metric path

Tags: java, hadoop, metrics, graphite, graphite-carbon

I use the following hadoop-metrics2.properties config:

```
*.sink.graphite.class=org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.sink.GraphiteSink
*.period=10
namenode.sink.graphite.server_host=alex-monitoring
namenode.sink.graphite.server_port=2015
namenode.sink.graphite.metrics_prefix=prefix
```

Carbon receives all metrics except FSNamesystem metrics, such as CapacityUsed, CapacityUsed etc (fully described [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.1.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/Metrics.html#FSNamesystem))

I dumped all tcp requests to carbon and this is what I've got:

```
<...>
prefix.dfs.FSNamesystem.Context=dfs.HAState=active.TotalSyncTimes=17 .Hostname=alex-hadoop1.TotalSyncCount 2 1550676511
prefix.dfs.FSNamesystem.Context=dfs.HAState=active.TotalSyncTimes=17 .Hostname=alex-hadoop1.NumInMaintenanceLiveDataNodes 0 1550676511
prefix.dfs.FSNamesystem.Context=dfs.HAState=active.TotalSyncTimes=17 .Hostname=alex-hadoop1.NumInMaintenanceDeadDataNodes 0 1550676511
<...>
```

The problem here is space in the path: `TotalSyncTimes=17 .Hostname=`
TotalSyncTimes should be a disctinct metric, but it appears in the metric path somehow with metric value after equals sign and also it is not send/recieved as distinct metric at all (because tcpdump doesn't catch packets with this metric as distrinct one).

Is it a problem with GraphiteSink or Hadoop metric 2, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Metric record is composed of tags (such as hostname, context, sessionid, etc.) and metrics (such as CapacityTotal, CapacityUsed, etc).

When a metric record is pushed into the `GraphiteSink` instance, it iterates over all of its tags, combines them into a prefix, and then export each metric (within that metric record) with the tag's prefix.

In Hadoop 2.9.1, the `TotalSyncTimes` (string) metric was introduced, which reflects time spent in sync operation on various edit logs - time for each active journal (e.g. "9 2 " means two active journals, 9 ms for the first, and 2 ms for the other).

Looking at HDFS's code (2.9.2 + 2.7.3), it looks like every metric of type string is automatically converted into a tag:

Definition of the problematic metric:

```
@Metric({"TotalSyncTimes",
              "Total time spend in sync operation on various edit logs"})
  public String getTotalSyncTimes() {
    JournalSet journalSet = fsImage.editLog.getJournalSet();
    if (journalSet != null) {
      return journalSet.getSyncTimes();
    } else {
      return "";
    }
  }
```

*(Notice that the Metric annotation is without the type, which is by default of type DEFAULT)*

Then, when it gets iterated, it will be converted to a string with a tag:

```
private MutableMetric newImpl(Type metricType) {
        Class<?> resType = this.method.getReturnType();
        switch(metricType) {
        case COUNTER:
            return this.newCounter(resType);
        case GAUGE:
            return this.newGauge(resType);
        case DEFAULT:
            return resType == String.class ? this.newTag(resType) : this.newGauge(resType);
        case TAG:
            return this.newTag(resType);
        default:
            Contracts.checkArg(metricType, false, "unsupported metric type");
            return null;
        }
    }
```

This means that `TotalSyncTimes` will be nested in a tag:

```
...
name: "Hadoop:service=NameNode,name=FSNamesystem",
modelerType: "FSNamesystem",
tag.Context: "dfs",
tag.HAState: "active",
tag.TotalSyncTimes: "9 2 ",
...
```

So, when a metric record with `TotalSyncTimes` is getting pushed to the  `GraphiteSink`, it will attach an invalid prefix (with space) to each of its metrics, just like you showed:

`HAState=active.TotalSyncTimes=17 .Hostname=alex-hadoop`

Bottom line, there are a couple of solutions you could take:

1. Using a different method (not via metrics2)
2. Creating a different graphite sink, which is more tag aware (what we did) and attach is to metrics2 instead of GrahpiteSink

By the way, I am still not sure if it's a bug in HDFS code or should be like that by design.